# How to create a heatmap with a huge value range?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to visualize a 2D Matrix having values ranging from -28000 to 728. I have used seaborn heatmap to get the visualization.

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
sns.heatmap(temp,annot=True,linewidths=.05,linecolor='blue')
```

But, I am not getting proper visualization because the range is very vast. what should I do in this case?
Attaching a snapshot of the visualization.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: There are solutions to this, but it depends on what you want to show. For example, you can clip the data to a smaller range with `np.clip` or plot it with, say, `vmin=-40` `vmax=10`; or you could, say, use `log10` of the `abs` of the values, so 10000=>4, 100=>2, 1=>1, which shows the range of the smaller values more than the larger ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
sns.heatmap(temp,annot=True,linewidths=.05,linecolor='blue',vmax=728,vmin=-28000)
```

use vmax, vmin to set the range

Comment: Yes, I have also used this approach but there is no effect. Both are giving the same results.

Comment: can you post the heatmap plot along with the question?

Comment: as per your data, most of the values are in range (-10,10). you should consider setting the range for heatmap as [vmax=10,vmin=-10] or any other value of your choice. This will set any value more than 10 as max of your scale, and any value less than -10 as min.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `sklearn`s `MinMaxScaler` to your data, then take `np.sqrt` or `np.log` of the result (you have to play around to see what works best.